# What is the 2018 way to implement social media logins on Android?

Tags: android, oauth, socialauth, social-authentication

I´ve implemented the Google and Facebook login manually, but the login buttons look differently so I was looking for a more convenient way to implement it.

There seems to be the **AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()** which seems to be deprecated. The JavaDoc says

> @deprecated this constant is no longer needed, use the {@link IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder}

So I´ve looked up the **Google Identity Toolkit**, but that seems to be out of development since 2013, at least according to this Github Repository

https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android

**Is there some common way to do it nowadays except from doing the button layouts manually to make them equal?**